# Different behaviors between train_on_batch and gradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a simple keras model on some data using

**approach 1**

```
model.train_on_batch(x, y)
```

and **approach 2**

```
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(model.variables)
    loss = my_loss(
        y_true=y,
        y_pred=model(x)
    )
    gradients = g.gradient(loss, model.variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(
              zip(gradients, model.variables)
    )
```

Even if the optimizer (Adam with some fixed learning rate) and the loss are the same, I do not get the exact same behavior. Is is expected ? (aka `train_on_batch` doing some additional stuff)

Comment: In approach 2, are you doing apply_gradients only once for the data in the training loop? Also can you please share the reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

In approach 1, `train_on_batch` trains using a single batch only and once. Runs a single gradient update on a single batch of data. The idea of using `train_on_batch` is probably to do more things between each batch.

In approach 2, gradient update depends on the frequency of `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))` in the training loop.

As gradient update is happening differently in both the cases, there might be difference in the model behavior.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.